# Accessing database object through SOAP web service

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am new to web service development. I need to develop a SOAP web service in java which access the data base object.
Is it possible to access the object of data base and which is of type TYPE. I have created a Type which is as follows:

```
create or replace 
TYPE XXXX_IN_O_TYPE
AS
OBJECT (USER_NAME  VARCHAR2(100), 
       USER_PASSWORD  VARCHAR2(50))
```

I need to access and assign value to USER_NAME and USER_PASSWORD from web service.
The values are entered by the user.
Is it possible through web service to access and manipulate customize object and its value.

Reply as soon as possible.

Comment: AFAIK, JDBC supports custom data types, but this does not relate to Web Services in any way. To answer your question - yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

I would suggest creating your web-service using JAX-WS, you will then need that web service to  interact with a database, perhaps with Hibernate.

Comment: Ok. thanks. But i am not aware with Hibernate. I created web service in core java. So if possible please suggest me of give me briefing of it or links or code snippet which helps me.